# Convert data type in R or Python

Tags: python, r

I have amazon data and would like to convert it into csv format either in R or in Python. The original data that I have look like as follows:

```
product/productId: B000GKXY3   
product/title: Nun Chuck  
product/price: 17.99  
review/userId: ADX8VLDUOL7BG  
review/profileName: M. Gingras


product/productId: B000GKXY34  
product/title: Nun Chuck  
product/price: 17.99  
review/userId: A3NM6P6BIWTIAE  
review/profileName: Maria Carpenter
```

And I want to change it into csv format looking like this:

```
product/productId, product/title, product/price, review/userId, review/profileName  
B000GKXY34, Nun Chuck, 17.99, ADX8VLDUOL7BG, M. Gingras  
B000GKXY34, Nun Chuck, 17.99, A3NM6P6BIWTIAE, Maria Carpenter
```

The amazon dataset looks a little unique to me and have no idea how to convert it into csv format.
I am mainly using R but also open to Python. So, anyone who knows how to do this with either R or Python, please share your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are fields known beforehand? Their number, names or/and order.

Comment: Building on @YuriyKovalev's comment: Calling each block a "record", is each record retrieved as a separate transaction?  Otherwise, how do you know that you have left one record and are entering a new record?  Exactly how is the data actually presented?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it in R. It requires that fields (order and names) are identical for all blocks of data, and that blocks of data are separated by blank lines. I imagine there are simpler ways to do this, perhaps with `plyr`?

Read in some data. You could point `readLines` at a text file.

```
dat <- readLines(textConnection('product/productId: B000GKXY3
product/title: Nun Chuck
product/price: 17.99
review/userId: ADX8VLDUOL7BG
review/profileName: M. Gingras

product/productId: B000GKXY34
product/title: Nun Chuck
product/price: 17.99
review/userId: A3NM6P6BIWTIAE
review/profileName: Maria Carpenter

product/productId: B000GKXY35
product/title: Nun Chuck
product/price: 17.99
review/userId: A3NM6P6BIWTIAF
review/profileName: Someone Else'))

# Identify blocks of data (assuming blank line indicates a new block) 
#  and split to list L.
L <- split(dat, rep(seq_along(diff(c(0, which(dat==''), length(dat)))), 
                   diff(c(0, which(dat==''), length(dat)))))

# Remove empty elements.
L <- lapply(L, function(x) x[x != ''])

# rbind to a matrix
M <- do.call(rbind, L)

# Extract column names
nm <- sub(':.*$', '', M[1, ])

# Remove column names from matrix elements
M <- gsub('^.*: *', '', M)

# Add column names attribute
colnames(M) <- nm

M

  product/productId product/title product/price review/userId    review/profileName
1 "B000GKXY3"       "Nun Chuck"   "17.99"       "ADX8VLDUOL7BG"  "M. Gingras"      
2 "B000GKXY34"      "Nun Chuck"   "17.99"       "A3NM6P6BIWTIAE" "Maria Carpenter" 
3 "B000GKXY35"      "Nun Chuck"   "17.99"       "A3NM6P6BIWTIAF" "Someone Else"
```

You could then easily coerce to a `data.frame` to make `product/price` numeric, if that floats your boat.

Comment: Running this code gives me one row with 17 columns.  Probably not what is intended.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: For me, with a clean workspace, it produces exactly what I've pasted as the final output (i.e., a 3x5 matrix). You do need to ensure that RStudio doesn't add tabs to the text within `textConnection`, but if reading from a text file, this isn't an issue. If you copy from the beginning of the code block, down to the `colnames` line, RStudio seems to not add the whitespace (RStudio 0.98.501).

Comment: I do indeed see leading tabs in `dat` starting at number 4.  I am using RStudio and didn't try pasting into a vanilla R session; should that matter?

Comment: The same happens to me, vanilla or not. But if you copy to the clipboard only up to the `colnames` line, this doesn't occur (for me). Note that you can also bulk untab by selecting lines and hitting shift-tab.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you own fixed list of fields. In this case, you can generate csv like this:

```
buff = [] # buffer with values for one output row
with open('source.txt') as inp:
    with open('target.txt', 'w') as out:
        for line in inp:
            if line == '\n': # blank string in input separates rows for output
                out.write('%s\n' % ','.join(buff))
                buff = [] # clear buffer
            else:
                buff.append(line.rstrip('\n').split(': ')[1])
        if buff: # if buffer is not empty, we have to write it to last row
            out.write('%s\n' % ','.join(buff))
```

Comment: I assume that this is Python (I'm not very familiar with Python and it sure isn't R).  This seems to rely on a fixed order of the fields in the input, which may be valid.  Also I don't see a header being printed.

Comment: You are completely right. Let's see, what @user3483546 will say about all this issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is consistent with your sample: ordered, 5 rows, 6th empty...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def partition(l, n):
    def _part():
        for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
            yield l[i:i+n]
    return [i for i in _part()]

def loadData():
    with open('data.dat') as f:
        return [row.split(': ') for row in f.read().splitlines() if row ]

data = partition(loadData(), 5)

headers = [[h[0] for h in data[0]]]
columns = [[col[1] for col in row] for row in data]

_data = headers + columns

print "\n".join(",".join(row) for row in _data)
```

results:

```
product/productId,product/title,product/price,review/userId,review/profileName
B000GKXY3,Nun Chuck,17.99,ADX8VLDUOL7BG,M. Gingras
B000GKXY34,Nun Chuck,17.99,A3NM6P6BIWTIAE,Maria Carpenter
```