# Converting amazon data into csv format in Python

Tags: python, csv

all, I asked similar question before but haven't solved it yet.

I have amazon review data set and would like to convert it into csv format in Python. The original data that I have look like as follows:

```
product/productId: B00032K32A
product/title: Cruiser Accessories 21330 Slim Rim, Chrome License Plate Frame
product/price: 4.99
review/userId: A2O41UFL8HAQWV
review/profileName: Nick Nefsik
review/helpfulness: 4/4
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1239667200
review/summary: It's slim, alright!
review/text: Similar to another review, I also found that this frame is more of a overlay to a   license plate (sits on top of the plate), as opposed to securing the plate underneath it, if that makes sense.It *just* covers the edges of my AZ plate, which is fine, but I sure wouldn't want it to be any smaller around its outside perimeter. I also ordered the chrome covers for the screws (Cruiser Accessories 82030 Screw Covers, Chrome) that I was already using, and, altogether, it looks great, and is exactly the look I was going for.

product/productId: B00032K32A
product/title: Cruiser Accessories 21330 Slim Rim, Chrome License Plate Frame
product/price: 4.99
review/userId: A3V7H58BH72AYT
review/profileName: Illustratedman
review/helpfulness: 6/7
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1199145600
review/summary: Nice...
review/text: I first purchased these for my new 2008 Honda Accord EX-L to complement the chrome on the car and though they looked nice I eventually ordered the 20130 version of the Cruiser chrome frame for the wider border.
```

The result should look like this:

```
product/productId, product/title, product/price, review/userId, review/profileName, review/helpfullness, review/score, review/time, review/summary, review/text
B00032K32A, Cruiser Accessories 21330 Slim Rim, Chrome License Plate Frame, 4.99, A2O41UFL8HAQWV, Nick Nefsik, 4/4, 5.0, 1239667200, It's slim, alright!, Similar to another review, I also found that this frame is more of a overlay to a   license plate (sits on top of the plate), as opposed to securing the plate underneath it, if that makes sense.It *just* covers the edges of my AZ plate, which is fine, but I sure wouldn't want it to be any smaller around its outside perimeter. I also ordered the chrome covers for the screws (Cruiser Accessories 82030 Screw Covers, Chrome) that I was already using, and, altogether, it looks great, and is exactly the look I was going for.
B00032K32A, Cruiser Accessories 21330 Slim Rim, Chrome License Plate Frame, 4.99, A3V7H58BH72AYT, Illustratedman, 6/7, 5.0, 1199145600, Nice..., I first purchased these for my new 2008 Honda Accord EX-L to complement the chrome on the car and though they looked nice I eventually ordered the 20130 version of the Cruiser chrome frame for the wider border.
```

I have pretty big amount of data (more than 300MB) with the same format above so want to write it instead of printing it.

I am a newbee to python and tried several different ways but still haven't succeeded it yet. Are there anyone who has a good thought about converting the original data type into csv format?

Comment: Quick Note: Your data contains commas. So when you convert the data set into a comma-separated file, the headings are not going to line up. You will have to convert the commas in your data to something else, like a '-' or something. Use the `replace` method for the string for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the solutions given for your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776691/convert-data-type-in-r-or-python) did not work, but here is another example of the same type of code. Note that you should change the `INPUT_FILE_NAME` and `OUTPUT_FILE_NAME` to suit your purpose.

```
INPUT_FILE_NAME = "Input.txt"
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "Output.csv"

header = [
    "product/productId",
    "product/title",
    "product/price",
    "review/userId",
    "review/profileName",
    "review/helpfulness",
    "review/score",
    "review/time",
    "review/summary",
    "review/text"]

f = open(INPUT_FILE_NAME)
outfile = open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"w")

# Write header
outfile.write(",".join(header) + "\n")

currentLine = []
for line in f:
   line = line.strip()
   if line == "": 
      outfile.write(",".join(currentLine))
      outfile.write("\n")
      currentLine = []
      continue
   parts = line.split(":",1)
   currentLine.append(parts[1])

if currentLine != []:
    outfile.write(",".join(currentLine))


f.close()
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution.  Create a class to represent the records in your data file.  Then iterate over each line of the data file mapping each line to a property on your Record object.  Then call a method on the object to format the record into the CSV format you want.

```
import string
import sys

file = open('amazon.txt')
csv = ''

class Record:
    def toCSV(self):
        return self.productId + ',' + self.title


record = Record()
for line in file:
    if '\n' == line:
        csv += record.toCSV()
    elif "productId" in line:
        record.productId = line
    elif "title" in line:
        record.title = line
    #add conditions for other fields in the datafile

file.close()

print csv
```